# PowerShell get name of folders in a path

Tags: powershell

I try to figure out some names of folders in a path.
For example:

```
C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5\folder6
```

how can i get the name of folder 2 or 3? Just as a String without any Slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.Split("\")` to the path folder

```
$pathfolder = "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4"
$pathfolder.Split("\")
```

---

```
cls
$pathfolder = "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4"
$A = $pathfolder.Split("\")
$Count = $pathfolder.Split("\").Count

For ($i=1; $i -le $Count+1; $i++) {
    echo $A[$i]
}
```

---

```
$pathfolder = "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4"
$A = $pathfolder.Split("\")

echo "The folder number 2 with name : " $A[2]
echo "The folder number 3 with name : " $A[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Get-ChildItem with the Directory and Depth command.

Something like

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Depth 6
```

This should return all Directory Names that are in the subfolder.

You could then pipe this into Select to grab just the name and parent directory.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Depth 6 | Select Name, Parent
```

*Edit*

If you want to go in the reverse direction because you have a file in folder 6 and want the name of folder 2 you could do something like this.

```
(get-item FileIn6.txt).directory.parent.parent.parent.parent | select Name
```

So if FileIn6.txt is a file sitting in folder 6, you get item and then grab the directory property, and the parent of that, parent of next, etc. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

```
$Path = "C:\f1\f2\"
$pspath = Get-ChildItem $Path
$namef2 = $pspath.Parent.Name
$namef2
$namef2.GetType().Name
$namef1 = $pspath.Parent.Parent.Name
$namef1
$namef1.GetType().Name
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.